# How to reflect changes in PATH as done by a user script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a script which does some basic root PATH integrity check and inputs a line in `~/.bash_profile` to source my script, so that changes my script made in root's `PATH` is permanent across restarts:

```
cat path_clean
#!/bin/bash

OLD_PATH=`echo $PATH`

OIFS=$IFS
IFS=:
for path in ${OLD_PATH}; do
    [ -d "${path}" ] || continue
    paths=( "${paths[@]}" "${path}" )
done

while read -r stat owner path; do
    [ "${owner}${stat:5:1}${stat:8:1}" = 'root--' ] || continue
    newpath="${newpath}:${path}"
done < <(stat -c "%A:%U:%n" "${paths[@]}" 2>/dev/null)

IFS=${OIFS}

NEW_PATH=${newpath#:}
export PATH=${NEW_PATH}
egrep "^[ ]*if.*fi;" ~/.bash_profile &> /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ];
then
   echo 'if [ -f /root/path_clean ]; then source /root/path_clean; fi;' >>     ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

Everything runs as expected when I run the script first time like this:

```
./path_clean
. ~/.bash_profile
```

But the script has one issue. If I do `. ~/.bash_profile` multiple times, then I see the value in PATH variable repeating itself every time.

For example before execution of script my `PATH` is:

```
[root@labeir1 ~]# echo $PATH
    /usr/bin/X11:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/ulticom/diameter/bin:/apps/omni/bin
```

Now after running `. ~/.bash_profile` first time, all is ok:

```
[root@labeir1 ~]# ./path_clean
[root@labeir1 ~]# echo $PATH <--still same as original `PATH`, which is ok
   /usr/bin/X11:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/ulticom/diameter/bin:/apps/omni/bin:/root/bin
[root@labeir1 ~]# . ~/.bash_profile <--now sourcing `.bash_profile`1st time
[root@labeir1 ~]# echo $PATH <--my script has changed `PATH` fine.
/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/ulticom/diameter/bin:/apps/omni/bin
[root@labeir1 ~]# . ~/.bash_profile
[root@labeir1 ~]# echo $PATH <-- problem starts
    /usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/ulticom/diameter/bin:/apps/omni/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/ulticom/diameter/bin:/apps/omni/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/ulticom/diameter/bin:/apps/omni/bin
[root@labeir1 ~]# . ~/.bash_profile
[root@labeir1 ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/ulticom/diameter/bin:/apps/omni/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/ulticom/diameter/bin:/apps/omni/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/ulticom/diameter/bin:/apps/omni/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/ulticom/diameter/bin:/apps/omni/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/ulticom/diameter/bin:/apps/omni/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/ulticom/diameter/bin:/apps/omni/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/ulticom/diameter/bin:/apps/omni/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/ulticom/diameter/bin:/apps/omni/bin
```

Please suggest what changes to make in the script in order to make it work fine and eradicate this problem.

Comment: ok, but normally this **will never happen**, as .bash_profile is only ever read **once** by bash, when it is from a login.

Answer (score 0):

[Use the correct check.](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test)

`[ -d … ]` checks if the given path is a directory, which your script obviously isn't.

You probably wanted `-f`, `-s`, or `-e`.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. My script has -f flag for the lines. I've edited my question to give a detail idea of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The two lines you added:

```
echo 'if [ -d /root/path_clean ]; then source /root/path_clean; fi;' >> /etc/profile
echo 'if [ -d /root/path_clean ]; then source /root/path_clean; fi; >> ~/.bash_profile
```

check for the existence of a *directory*; you most likely meant:

```
echo 'if [ -f /root/path_clean ]; then source /root/path_clean; fi;' >> /etc/profile
echo 'if [ -f /root/path_clean ]; then source /root/path_clean; fi; >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Note the "-f" inside the brackets.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. My script has `-f` flag for the lines. I've edited my question to give a detail idea of the issue.